# Blank page "The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme." on WordPress Vagrant

Tags: php, wordpress, gulp, vagrant

I have a blank page when accessing my local, however I can login fine into `/wp_admin` and change the theme. In the appearances menu, I have:

`The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme.`

How can I solve this?

---

Some info hopefully to help you understand. As this is a Vagrant install, in the site root, I have:

```
/web
/assets
```

In `web`, we have the Wordpress install. `web/wp/wp_content/themes` contains all default Wordpress themes i.e. twentythirteen. when set, these themes work ok.

In `assets`, I have the actual custom theme, which needs to remain in that folder, as Gulp regenerates the theme and `/less` and `/js` files in case of changes. This is the theme which displays as broken in the admin.

The custom theme is referenced with a file in `web/app/themes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

If anyone comes across this issue, update your VirtualBox to latest. Theme's symbolic link was generating back slashes to the path like `..\..\` and it should have been `../../assets/theme_name`